# Having difficulty setting up Asp.net(Framework) project with typescript

Tags: angular

I want to use angular2 with typescript in my asp.net application in conjunction with web api. I am following this link to setup typescript and having trouble understanding one instruction
https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/asp-net-4.html

The section I am not able to understand is

Add a CopyFiles target to the build

Finally, we need to make sure that the Angular files are copied as part of the build. To do this, edit the project by right-clicking ‘Unload’ and then ‘Edit csproj’. **After the TypeScript configuration PropertyGroup, add a new ItemGroup and Target to copy the angular files.**

The part in bold does not make any sense. I dont see a typescript configuration property group in the project when I open it for edit.

I will really appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than specifying the TypeScript settings in the `.csproj` I suggest to instead use a `tsconfig.json` file in the root of you project(s). To take advantage of all new features, download TypeScript 2.x. A sample file, in this case using SystemJS as module loader, could look like this:

```
{
    "compileOnSave": true,
    "compilerOptions":
    {
        "target": "es5",
        "module": "system",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "removeComments": false,
        "noImplicitAny": false,
        "baseUrl": ".",
        "outDir": "Assets/Scripts",
        "paths":
        {
            "@angular/core":        [ "/Packages/jspm/npm/@angular/core@2.0.1/index" ],
            "@angular/compiler":    [ "/Packages/jspm/npm/@angular/compiler@2.0.1/index" ],
            "rxjs/*":               [ "/Packages/jspm/npm/rxjs@5.0.0-beta.12/*" ],
        }
    }
}
```

This `outDir` property will output all TypeScript files (and folder structure of you TypeScript files) to the folder "Assets/Scripts" which you could include in your `.gitignore` for example. The path settings are for module resolution (and IntelliSense) when using import statements within VS2015 in conjunction with JSPM. I believe using `npm` to manage your modules does not require that, but you have to try. If anyone knows a better way of telling VS where to look for Angular, I would appreciate a hint.

If you need further help setting up your environment, please let me know.

Comment: Thanks a lot Tobias. I do have tsconfig. The typescriptlang.org setup instructions for asp.net 4 specifiy adding tsconfig. I added that at the root of the project. With that in place, I do get tsconfig files transpiled to js and placed in the path specified in outDir.

Comment: The part where I mentioned I am having problem is following is under - Adding angular2. In that section under "Add a CopyFiles target to the build", I am able to follow the part on editing project to add section specified in the instructions.

Comment: If you are using a tsconfig.json file you don't need to alter the project file directly in any way (as far a I know). Sorry if I misunderstood you, is the problem how to get angular installed into your project?

Comment: Yeah, the problem is with how to get angular 2 installed in project. I am only following the typsescriptlang.org link documentation for it.

Comment: Is there any other link I could follow for the setup, the asp.net core has the details on angular 1.xxx but I havent found anything useful so far on 2.0 setup

Comment: I personally don't use the integrated package manager in VS, so first you wanna install node.js on your machine. With that you can use "npm" to install JSPM ("npm install -g jspm"), which in turn installs system.js for you modules (aka. TypeScript-classes / files). Use "jspm init" and from your project directory, where your package.jspn resides, to initialize JSPM. For a simple starter project, choose a "jspm_packages" path below wwwroot. You need to include system.js and config.js with your applications and you are good to go.

Comment: After that you can use "jspm install npm:@angular/common", "jspm install npm:@angular/core", etc. to install angular. You require them by importing them to you files. It's a bit complicated if you never done it before, so please let me know if you still have trouble to get it up and running.

Comment: Here is a VS extension that provides templates that make use of WebPack as well as server side rendering:
https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/31a3eab5-e62b-4030-9226-b5e4c9e1ffb5
Here is the source and a brief description:

http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2016/10/04/angular2-template-for-visual-studio/

Comment: Thanks a lot Tobias!, I am going to try your suggestions and will get back to you.

Comment: Hi Tobias, thanks for your help on this. I was able to setup my application with angular 2 and typescript. I followed the quickstart tutorial on angular site. There was one mistake in that tutorial too in setting system.config.js, but after fixing that I am able to use angular2 with typescript.